# Python writes part of a string into a csv row

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write all the hits of a tag into csv file in Python.
My string is:

```
<pre class="CodeRay highlight"><code data-lang="java"><span class="annotation">@CDIUI</span>(<span class="string"><span class="delimiter">"</span><span class="content">cdievents</span><span class="delimiter">"</span></span>)
<span class="annotation">@Theme</span>(<span class="string"><span class="delimiter">"</span><span class="content">valo</span><span class="delimiter">"</span></span>)
<span class="directive">public</span> <span class="type">class</span> <span class="class">CDIEventUI</span> <span class="directive">extends</span> UI {
    <span class="annotation">@Inject</span>
    InputPanel inputPanel;

    <span class="annotation">@Inject</span>
    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    <span class="annotation">@Override</span>
    <span class="directive">protected</span> <span class="type">void</span> init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Layout content =
            <span class="keyword">new</span> HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);
        setContent(content);
    }
}</code></pre>
```

My python code for writing the hits to a csv file is:

```
hits =  soup.find_all("pre", "CodeRay highlight")# "programlisting")
f = open('extractedsuorceTEST2.csv','ab')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(('page', hits[0].text.encode('UTF-8').replace('Â',' ')))
```

By this code hits[0] is :

```
'@CDIUI("cdievents")\n@Theme("valo")\npublic class CDIEventUI extends UI {\n    @Inject\n    InputPanel inputPanel;\n\n    @Inject\n    DisplayPanel displayPanel;\n\n    @Override\n    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {\n        Layout content =\n            new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);\n        setContent(content);\n    }\n}'
```

But the result written in csv file is :

```
@CDIUI(""cdievents"")
@Theme(""valo"")
public class CDIEventUI extends UI {
    @Inject
    InputPanel inputPanel;

    @Inject
    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Layout content =
```

When it should be :

```
@CDIUI("cdievents")
@Theme("valo")
public class CDIEventUI extends UI {
    @Inject
    InputPanel inputPanel;

    @Inject
    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Layout content =
            new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);
        setContent(content);
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest a solution?
Thanks

Comment: What does `hits[0].text.encode('UTF-8').replace('Â',' ')` contain?

Comment: hits[0].text.encode('UTF-8').replace('Â',' ') : '@CDIUI("cdievents")\n@Theme("valo")\npublic class CDIEventUI extends UI {\n    @Inject\n    InputPanel inputPanel;\n\n    @Inject\n    DisplayPanel displayPanel;\n\n    @Override\n    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {\n        Layout content =\n            new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);\n        setContent(content);\n    }\n}'

Comment: The string here is complete but when I write it in CSV file using "writer.writerow" it is truncated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful to not just abandon the file or CSVWriter objects.

Try changing you code to

```
hits =  soup.find_all("pre", "CodeRay highlight")# "programlisting")
with open('extractedsuorceTEST2.csv','ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(('page', hits[0].text.encode('UTF-8').replace('Â',' ')))
```

If it still fails, check the [field size limit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.field_size_limit) and increase it as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what about the rest of the string that is truncated: new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);
        setContent(content);
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that that was what the question was about. I spotted the first difference but not the truncation. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, CSVWriter does not provide context manager functionality. Remembered that wrongly and did not check the docs. I've fixed my code.

Comment: It again truncates the string. When I try to write hits[0] in a txt file it is written just fine. The problem seems to be with some kind if limitation for data in a csv cell.

Comment: I've run your code without changing `field_size_limit` and it works fine for me. Could it be that your problem has something to do with character encoding?

Comment: If you feed the string `'@CDIUI("cdievents")\n@Theme("valo")\npublic class CDIEventUI extends UI {\n @Inject\n InputPanel inputPanel;\n\n @Inject\n DisplayPanel displayPanel;\n\n @Override\n protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {\n Layout content =\n new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);\n setContent(content);\n }\n}' .replace('\n', "\n")` (copied from above) into your code instead of reading from the web page, does it work?

Comment: hits = '@CDIUI("cdievents")\n@Theme("valo")\npublic class CDIEventUI extends UI {\n @Inject\n InputPanel inputPanel;\n\n @Inject\n DisplayPanel displayPanel;\n\n @Override\n protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {\n Layout content =\n new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, displayPanel);\n setContent(content);\n }\n}'.replace('\n', "\n")    
with open('extractedsuorceTEST2.csv','ab') as f:
 csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
 writer = csv.writer(f,quotechar='"') 
 writer.writerow(('page',hits))

Comment: As you said I fed the string directly and the output changed to:

Comment: Layout content =
 new HorizontalLayout(inputPanel, di

Comment: a new line was added to the output. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, this is all very mysterious and I'm running out of ideas as to how this could be resolved without me being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "being able to reproduce it"? Do you need the .py file? Or should I look for answers someplace else?

Comment: If you are comfortable sharing the complete file, put it in your question. However, everything worked fine for me when I used what you tried last, so I suspect it will work fine with the whole script as well. But, give it a try.